# How do you change the page name for Paginator?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Current `Paginator` is using `?page=N`, but I want to use something else. How can I change so it's `?sida=N` instead?

I've looked at `Illuminate\Pagination\Environment` and there is a method (`setPageName()`) there to change it (I assume), but how do you use it?

In the `Paginator` class there is a method the change the base url (`setBaseUrl()`) in the `Environment` class, but there is no method for setting a page name. Do I really need to extend the `Paginator` class just to be able to change the page name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like you said you can use the `setPageName` method:

```
Paginator::setPageName('sida');
```

You can place that in `app/start/global.php`.

Answer (score 10):

Just came across this same issue for `5.1` and you can pass the page name like this:

```php
Post::paginate(1, ['*'], 'new-page-name');
```

Comment: The thing is that you want this globally. You don't want to add this every time you want to use `paginate`.

Answer (score 4):

Well that didnt work for me in laravel 5 , in laravel 5 you will need to do more extra work by overriding the PaginationServiceProvider because the queryName "page" was hardcoded in there , so first create your new PaginationServiceProvider in /app/providers ,This was mine

```
<?php 
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class PaginationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    //boot 
    public function boot()
    {

        Paginator::currentPageResolver(function()
        {
            return $this->app['request']->input('p');
        });

    }//end boot 


     public function register()
    {
        //
    }


}
```

Then in your controllers you can do this

```
$users = User::where("status","=",1)
         ->paginate(5)
         ->setPageName("p");
```

Comment: I just implemented this, and it appears that with the service provider, you don't need to call `setPageName()` in your Eloquent query.