# Laravel 5.4 Pagination Set pageName Globally

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.4

I make query to set pagename in almost every controller, and only repeat the same things `paginate(10, ['*'], 'p')`.

```
$statuses = \App\Status::select('id', 'name', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10, ['*'], 'p');
```

How to make set pagename globally? Thank you.

Comment: One https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731024/how-do-you-change-the-page-name-for-paginator Two https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18342

Comment: @u_mulder where is `app/start/global.php`?

Comment: In order to go manually to a specific page you don't have to write the pagename but just this http://localhost:8080/status?page=2. Assuming that `/status` is the page you view the pagination

Comment: @Onix Sorry, I have updated the question.